# Table rate for different customer group

Tags: magento

Is there any way to define different table rate for different customer group in Magento?

I want to create group ABC and have it different shipping rate than rest of other users.

Comment: How did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use any shipping module and customize the method  ( [Matrixrate](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/webshopapps-matrixrate-1-multiple-table-rates-extension-certified-bug-free.html) is very good module )

And Modify collectRates() method in ( ../model/Carrier/{ShippingMethod}.php )

```
public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request){
.....
$customer = Mage::helper('customer')->getCustomer();
$group = null;
if($customer)
{
    $group = $customer->getGroupId();
}
if($group == 'ID'){
// do the logic here 
}else{
return false; // disable the shipping method
}
......
}
```

method to check on the customer group and return rate or false;